# WordPress help for my template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site in wordpress which is like this

http://villazanini.com.br/

There is form on the map which is on home page which includes following labels

location 
type 
beds 
text

I want to change them to include my own text

where and how can i edit this widget to include my own text ?

Answer (score 0):

At least 2 options if you can't make modifications using the Realia theme settings:

1. Go into your wp-content/themes/realia directory and look for a file/directory with the theme's widgets in it. Might be in the assets directory. Look for the Property Filter widget. Open that php file with your text editor. Search for `<label class="control-label" for="inputBeds-">Beds</label>` and replace "Beds" with whatever text you like. Do this for the other fields. Save the file and you're done. The only problem is if you update your theme, you may lose your edits and have to do this again if the theme author modifies the widget.
2. You can create a javascript file to change the text for each html node. That's a little more involved. You have to write the script and enqueue it. This approach usually survives theme updates.